# Is it possible to track a user who using proxy website?

Tags: web-services, proxy

Is it possible to track a users ip address who using proxy website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible for **proxy websites** which is what you are asking (sites like anonymizer.com)

It is not possible with proxy gateways since proxies intercept all client requests and then in turn relay that, so by design you cannot determine the IP of the originator. This is what the other responses are alluding to.

However, the way proxy websites work is to convert all links of the form `resource.aspx` to  `proxy.com?resource.aspx`. This means that if you have **AJAX requests** you may be able to skip the proxy and have the client relay the request directly to the server there by getting the client IP. You could also use **Adobe Flash** to communicate directly with the client and bypass the website proxy.

Comment: Challenge here is that very often client IPs are private network addresses e.g. 10.* and 192.168.* addresses.  I'd be very cautious to rely on such data being unique.

Comment: @stephbu, this is regarding proxy websites, not proxy gateways so that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 4):

Some proxy servers add a [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) header to proxied requests.

Don't expect it to be always there and it may even contain false and/or invalid information, so it is not 100% reliable.

Comment: x-forwarded-for can also be used in legit scenarios.  Beware of counting on this.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the proxy will add the Header: X-Forwarded-For, but that is sporadic at best.

Answer (score 1):

Negatory. Nope. Not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `HTTP_VIA`, `HTTP_FORWARDED`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, additional guess could be made if  `REMOTE_HOST` or `HTTP_USER_AGENT` contains the word "via", "squid", "proxy", "cache" or "delegate". An anonymous proxy would likely hide these things.

Answer (score 0):

Go for X-Forwarded-For header to proxied requests.